# Can const std::array member reference be initialized with an rvalue?

Tags: c++, initialization, rvalue-reference, stdarray

I was trying to initialize a class member `const std::array` reference with an initializer list:

```
class Foo {
    const std::array<const int&, 3> &bar;
    Foo() : bar({ 1, 2, 3 }) {}
}
```

But apparantly

> cannot initialize reference type 'const std::array &' with a parenthesized initializer list

**Q: Is there a way to initialize a `const std::array` reference member with an rvalue?**

Comment: The temporary is destroyed after the construtor finishes. You need to find a different approach.

Comment: C++ doesn't have special rules for `std::array`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they pretty much answer the question. I'll post my conclusions as an answer.

Comment: I also edited the question to specify _member_ references.

Comment: Making this `Foo f{{1,2,3}};` will make it work, but requires `Foo` to be aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments on the question I can conclude I didn't realize two things:

- `const` reference members aren't the same as `const` reference non-members, in that they don't extend the lifespan of temporary values.
- Class members can be initialized in the constructor with curly braces (where applicable, e.g. arrays).

As an additional note, a member `std::array` containing `T&` can cause the following:

- > warning: 'Foo' has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
- > error: forming pointer to reference type 'std::array::value_type {aka const int&}'

In both cases, I'm not entirely sure what's going on, but those would be separate questions.

Comment: Your warning about non-virtual destructors is in part a reference to C++ abstract classes.